# How to call only few method asynchronously in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, c#-8.0

I know this question has been asked for many times on stack overflow but I am looking for some suggestion on my below code.
 In my application there are many synchronous methods which are hard to modify. I cannot change everything to async await. But I want to run few methods asynchronously.
I have written some code for that. Also I have added the comments that will help to understand my requirement.

Here is my code:

```
    //This class will perform some heavy operation and also going to call an API for tax configuration.
    //The original class takes almost 2 sec to respond. Obviously we are refactoring it but also want this class methods to run async way
    public static class TaxCalculatorHelper
    {
        public static Task<double> CalculateTaxAsync(double salary)
        {             
            // I will do some heavy tax calculation here, so I want it to run asynchronously
            return Task.FromResult(500.00); // currently returning temporary value
        }
    }

    //The exisiting classes 
    public class Employee
    {
        //This method is not going to be async but What I want that Tax calculation which is heavy task that should run asynchronously        
        public double GetEmployeeFinalSalary(double salary)
        {
            var taxValue = Task.Run(async () => await TaxCalculatorHelper.CalculateTaxAsync(salary));

            //I was doing this
            //  return taxValue.Result; // I cannot use this because it blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete

            //Is the below approach correct ?
            return taxValue.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
        }
    }

    public class SomeOtherClass
    {
        private readonly Employee _employee;
        public SomeOtherClass()
        {
            _employee = new Employee();
        }

        //This will not be async
        public void GetEmployeeCtc(double salary)
        {
            var finalCtc = _employee.GetEmployeeFinalSalary(salary);
        }
    }
```

Can anybody review and suggest me the best approach ?
Thank you !!

Comment: Point of running  something async usualy either to save resources(so thread can be used for some other work) if your operation is "truly" asynchronous or continue doing some stuff  in your method while some work is done in parallel. Neither of which will be achieved in this case. If you want `GetEmployeeFinalSalary` not to block calling thread you need to make it async or returning Task(so the caller will decide what and how to do with it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is a UI application, then using `Task.Run` to push synchronous work off the UI thread is an acceptable approach. It's *not* a good idea in ASP.NET apps.

For your specific situation, you need to decide what to do about `GetEmployeeFinalSalary`.

```
//This method is not going to be async but What I want that Tax calculation which is heavy task that should run asynchronously        
...
//  return taxValue.Result; // I cannot use this because it blocks the calling thread until the asynchronous operation is complete
```

You need to decide whether `GetEmployeeFinalSalary` will be synchronous or asynchronous. If it's synchronous, then it will block the calling thread - that's what synchronous *means*.

I suspect that you do *not* want to block the calling thread (I'm assuming that's the UI thread). In that case, `GetEmployeeFinalSalary` *must* be asynchronous in order to free up the calling thread:

```
public async Task<double> GetEmployeeFinalSalaryAsync(double salary)
{
  return await Task.Run(async () => await TaxCalculatorHelper.CalculateTaxAsync(salary));
}
```

Comment: In your final code block, is it ok to call `CalculateTaxAsync ` synchronously in the `Task` ?

Comment: @HMZ: If `CalculateTaxAsync` was synchronous, then yes, the invocation would be synchronous.

Comment: Doesn't his overlook the fact that `CalculateTaxAsync` is actually a synchronous method? Not that it will have a huge impact on output, but it leaves the code with detritus.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay: "This class will perform some heavy operation and also going to call an API for tax configuration." And they're planning on refactoring it, just not yet.

Comment: Ah OK yes; I saw the comment `// I will do some heavy tax calculation here,` and assumed CPU.

Comment: Sorry if this obvious to you, but since we're calling `CalculateTaxAsync` inside a `Task` what's the difference between calling it synchronously and asynchronously in terms of performance as long as we're awaiting the main executing task? and for the sake of the argument lets assume we have two versions of this method sync and async.

Comment: @HMZ: I assume you mean "as long as we're calling it from `Task.Run`", not "as long as we're awaiting the main executing task". The difference would be that the asynchronous version would not use a thread pool thread for the duration of the API call.

Comment: @HMZ Do you mean why not do this: `Task.Run(() => TaxCalculatorHelper.CalculateTaxAsync(salary))`? That would behave the same, as `CalculateTaxAsync` returns a `Task`, just like the `async` lambda. In fact it slightly reduces overhead as there is 1 less `Task` created.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay my point was if we have `CalculateTax` and `CalculateTaxAsync` would awaiting the `CalculateTaxAsync` like: `await Task.Run(async () => await CalculateTaxAsync())` be any different from calling `await Task.Run(() => CalculateTax())`? but from i what i understood from @StephenCleary is that the `async` version won't hold on to the caller thread until the API response has arrived and it (The caller thread) would be free to do work while the response hasn't arrived yet. am i in the wrong here?

Comment: @HMZ Both examples will behave the same from the caller's perspective, as `Task.Run` returns immediately, irrespective of the callback. They are, however, calling different overloads of `Task.Run`; the sync version uses `Task.Run(Func<TResult>)`, whereas the async version uses `Task.Run(Func<Task<TResult>>)`. This determines how the code will run on the thread pool, and may or may not be a consideration. Ideally, if the code truly is `async`, then it should be written as such, so as to not block any thread, whether that be the current thread, or one on the thread pool.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thank you! i got it.